# dplyr Filter Database Table with Large Number of Matches

Tags: r, database, dplyr, dbplyr

I am working with `dplyr` and the `dbplyr` package to interface with my database.  I have a table with millions of records.  I also have a list of values that correspond to the key in that same table I wish to filter.  Normally I would do something like this to filter the table.

```
library(ROracle)

# connect info omitted
con <- dbConnect(...)

# df with values - my_values

con %>% tbl('MY_TABLE') %>% filter(FIELD %in% my_values$FIELD)
```

However, that `my_values` object contains over 500K entries (hence why I don't provide actual data here).  This is clearly not efficient when they will basically be put in an `IN` statement (It essentially hangs).  Normally if I was writing SQL, I would create a temporary table and write a `WHERE EXISTS` clause.  But in this instance, I don't have write privileges.

How can I make this query more efficient in R?

Comment: Maybe an inner join?

Answer (score 1):

Note sure whether this will help, but a few suggestions:

1. Find other criteria for filtering. For example, if `my_values$FIELD` is consecutive or the list of values can be inferred by some other columns, you can seek help from the `between` filter: `filter(between(FIELD, a, b))`?
2. Divide and conquer. Split `my_values` into small batches, make queries for each batch, then combine the results. This may take a while, but should be stable and worth the wait.

Comment: Thanks for response, unfortunately the values are not consecutive so option 1 is out.  Option 2 should work but I'm hoping for other possibilities here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your restrictions, I would approach it similar to how Polor Beer suggested, but I would send one db command per value using `purrr::map` and then use `dplyr::bindrows()` at the end.  This way you'll have a nice piped code that will adapt if your list changes.  Not ideal, but unless you're willing to write a SQL table variable manually, not sure of any other solutions.